# Order flex item at last position always

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I have a flex container like below :

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    .
    .
    .
    <div class="child">n</div>
</div>
```

the `child` number varies everytime. I need `second child` to always be at last in mobile device.

I am aware `order: -1` can be used to place it at first place everytime. But I'm interested in knowing if there's anything I can do to order it at last position everytime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally the elements are laid out in the order of their appearance in the markup. However you can specify an implicit ordering using the `order` property in css. This will place elements according to their order. If two elements have the same value for this order property, they will stay be layed out following the original markup. In a way you can see it as form of grouping: first the ones with order 0, then with order 1, .... (setting a negative value for order would of course place them *before* the 0 group; that is how the -1 trick to place the element first works)

You can use this solve your problem by simply setting the `order` of the second child to `1`, all other elements will have the default value of 0 so be placed before.

```
.child:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephane that's exactly I was looking for. Just didn't knew by default all items have default order as 0.